# VSTS 2017 CI for UWP Application Fails To Find Files (NuGet Package Task Error Too)

Tags: c#, uwp, nuget, azure-pipelines-build-task

I am sure it is user error, but many of the Microsoft documents are either written for a VSTS admin or are honestly out of date (as in the steps do not even match the UI for VisualStudio Online.) I have done the best I can to get this fired up and working.

The Error:

```
******************************************************************************
Starting: NuGet Install for SNR3
******************************************************************************
==============================================================================
Task         : NuGet Restore
Description  : Restores NuGet packages in preparation for a Visual Studio Build step.
Version      : 1.0.0
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : [More Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=613747)
==============================================================================
C:\Windows\system32\chcp.com 65001
Active code page: 65001
Error: Not found files: d:\a\3\s\SNR3.sln
Packages failed to restore
```

The Error v2:

```
******************************************************************************
Starting: NuGet Install for SNR3
******************************************************************************
==============================================================================
Task         : NuGet Installer
Description  : Installs or restores missing NuGet packages
Version      : 0.2.31
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : [More Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=613747)
==============================================================================
C:\Windows\system32\chcp.com 65001
Active code page: 65001
Error: Not found files: d:\a\3\s\SNR3.sln
Packages failed to install
```

Full Log:

```
 Hosted Agent successfully assigned.
 Configuring connection settings for Hosted Agent
 Starting Hosted Agent
 Initializing connection to Hosted Agent
 ##[section]Starting: Build
 Current agent version: '2.116.1'
 ##[debug]Cleaning agent temp folder: d:\a\_temp
 ##[debug]SET TMP=d:\a\_temp
 ##[debug]SET TEMP=d:\a\_temp
 ##[section]Starting: Initialize Job
 ##[debug]Primary repository: Contracts. repository type: TfsVersionControl
 Prepare build directory.
 ##[debug]Creating build directory: 'd:\a\1'
 ##[debug]Delete existing artifacts directory: 'd:\a\1\a'
 ##[debug]Creating artifacts directory: 'd:\a\1\a'
 ##[debug]Delete existing test results directory: 'd:\a\1\TestResults'
 ##[debug]Creating test results directory: 'd:\a\1\TestResults'
 ##[debug]Creating binaries directory: 'd:\a\1\b'
 ##[debug]Creating source directory: 'd:\a\1\s'
 Set build variables.
 Download all required tasks.
 Downloading task: NuGetInstaller
 ##[debug]Task 'NuGetInstaller' has been downloaded into 'd:\a\_tasks\NuGetInstaller_333b11bd-d341-40d9-afcf-b32d5ce6f23b\0.2.31'.
 Downloading task: VSBuild
 ##[debug]Task 'VSBuild' has been downloaded into 'd:\a\_tasks\VSBuild_71a9a2d3-a98a-4caa-96ab-affca411ecda\1.113.0'.
 Downloading task: PublishBuildArtifacts
 ##[debug]Task 'PublishBuildArtifacts' has been downloaded into 'd:\a\_tasks\PublishBuildArtifacts_2ff763a7-ce83-4e1f-bc89-0ae63477cebe\1.0.41'.
 ##[section]Finishing: Initialize Job
 ##[debug]Evaluating condition for step: 'Get Sources'
 ##[debug]Evaluating: succeeded()
 ##[debug]Evaluating succeeded:
 ##[debug]=> (Boolean) True
 ##[debug]Expanded: True
 ##[debug]Result: True
 ##[section]Starting: Get Sources
 ##[debug]Sync source for endpoint: Contracts
 Prepending Path environment variable with directory containing 'tf.exe'.
 ##[debug]Path: 'C:\LR\mms\Services\Mms\Provisioner\TaskAgent\agents\2.116.1\externals\vstsom;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.4\;C:\Users\VssAdministrator\.dnx\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft DNX\Dnvm\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Emulator Manager\1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI\wbin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform ...
 Querying workspace information.
 ##[debug]tf vc workspaces /format:xml /collection:https://houseofcat.visualstudio.com/ /loginType:OAuth /login:.,******** /noprompt
 ##[debug]<Workspaces />
 ##[debug]Sources directory does not exist or is empty.
 ##[debug]tf vc workspaces ws_1_1 /computer:* /format:xml /collection:https://houseofcat.visualstudio.com/ /loginType:OAuth /login:.,******** /noprompt
 ##[debug]<Workspaces>
 ##[debug] <Workspace computer="FACTORYVM-38" islocal="true" name="ws_1_1" ownerdisp="Project Collection Build Service (bytemedev)" ownerid="b58bda4f-3d2b-42b9-92af-0459c5f935e1:Build:6efb2b2a-0a99-489e-826b-892f9a3ad494" ownertype="Microsoft.TeamFoundation.ServiceIdentity" owner="c1289161-e96b-4d2f-8b38-2d28cb3f20de" owneruniq="c1289161-e96b-4d2f-8b38-2d28cb3f20de">
 ##[debug] <Comment />
 ##[debug] <Folders>
 ##[debug] <WorkingFolder local="d:\a\1\s\Contracts" item="$/Contracts" />
 ##[debug] <WorkingFolder item="$/Contracts/Drops" type="Cloak" />
 ##[debug] </Folders>
 ##[debug] <LastAccessDate>2017-05-14T20:57:33.677+00:00</LastAccessDate>
 ##[debug] <OwnerAliases>
 ##[debug] <string>Build\6efb2b2a-0a99-489e-826b-892f9a3ad494</string>
 ##[debug] <string>6efb2b2a-0a99-489e-826b-892f9a3ad494</string>
 ##[debug] <string>Project Collection Build Service (bytemedev)</string>
 ##[debug] </OwnerAliases>
 ##[debug] </Workspace>
 ##[debug]</Workspaces>
 ##[command]tf vc workspace /delete ws_1_1;c1289161-e96b-4d2f-8b38-2d28cb3f20de /collection:https://houseofcat.visualstudio.com/ /loginType:OAuth /login:.,******** /noprompt
 ##[debug]Deleting: 'd:\a\1\s'.
 ##[command]tf vc workspace /new /location:local /permission:Public ws_1_1 /collection:https://houseofcat.visualstudio.com/ /loginType:OAuth /login:.,******** /noprompt
 ##[command]tf vc workfold /unmap /workspace:ws_1_1 $/ /collection:https://houseofcat.visualstudio.com/ /loginType:OAuth /login:.,******** /noprompt
 ##[command]tf vc workfold /map /workspace:ws_1_1 $/Contracts d:\a\1\s\Contracts /collection:https://houseofcat.visualstudio.com/ /loginType:OAuth /login:.,******** /noprompt
 ##[command]tf vc workfold /cloak /workspace:ws_1_1 $/Contracts/Drops /collection:https://houseofcat.visualstudio.com/ /loginType:OAuth /login:.,******** /noprompt
 ##[command]tf vc get /version:497 /recursive /overwrite d:\a\1\s /loginType:OAuth /login:.,******** /noprompt
 All files are up to date.
 ##[section]Finishing: Get Sources
 ##[debug]Evaluating condition for step: 'NuGet install $/Contracts/SNR3/SNR3.sln'
 ##[debug]Evaluating: succeeded()
 ##[debug]Evaluating succeeded:
 ##[debug]=> (Boolean) True
 ##[debug]Expanded: True
 ##[debug]Result: True
 ##[section]Starting: NuGet install $/Contracts/SNR3/SNR3.sln
 ==============================================================================
 Task : NuGet Installer
 Description : Installs or restores missing NuGet packages
 Version : 0.2.31
 Author : Microsoft Corporation
 Help : [More Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=613747)
 ==============================================================================
 ##[debug]tf vc resolvePath $\Contracts\SNR3\SNR3.sln /loginType:OAuth /login:.,******** /noprompt
 ##[debug]d:\a\1\s\Contracts\SNR3\SNR3.sln
 ##[debug]tf vc resolvePath $\Contracts\SNR3\SNR3\nuget.config /loginType:OAuth /login:.,******** /noprompt
 ##[debug]d:\a\1\s\Contracts\SNR3\SNR3\nuget.config
 ##[debug]agent.workFolder=d:\a
 ##[debug]loading inputs and endpoints
 ##[debug]loading ENDPOINT_AUTH_$/
 ##[debug]loading ENDPOINT_AUTH_PARAMETER_$/_ACCESSTOKEN
 ##[debug]loading ENDPOINT_AUTH_PARAMETER_SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION_ACCESSTOKEN
 ##[debug]loading ENDPOINT_AUTH_SCHEME_$/
 ##[debug]loading ENDPOINT_AUTH_SCHEME_SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION
 ##[debug]loading ENDPOINT_AUTH_SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION
 ##[debug]loading INPUT_NOCACHE
 ##[debug]loading INPUT_NUGETCONFIGPATH
 ##[debug]loading INPUT_NUGETVERSION
 ##[debug]loading INPUT_RESTOREMODE
 ##[debug]loading INPUT_SOLUTION
 ##[debug]loading INPUT_VERBOSITY
 ##[debug]loaded 12
 ##[debug]check path : d:\a\_tasks\NuGetInstaller_333b11bd-d341-40d9-afcf-b32d5ce6f23b\0.2.31\task.json
 ##[debug]set resource file to: d:\a\_tasks\NuGetInstaller_333b11bd-d341-40d9-afcf-b32d5ce6f23b\0.2.31\task.json
 ##[debug]system.culture=en-US
 ##[debug]Absolute path for pathSegments: C:\Windows\system32\chcp.com = C:\Windows\system32\chcp.com
 ##[debug]check path : C:\Windows\system32\chcp.com
 ##[debug]C:\Windows\system32\chcp.com=C:\Windows\system32\chcp.com
 ##[debug]C:\Windows\system32\chcp.com arg: ["65001"]
 ##[debug]C:\Windows\system32\chcp.com arg: ["65001"]
 ##[debug]exec tool: C:\Windows\system32\chcp.com
 ##[debug]exec tool: C:\Windows\system32\chcp.com
 ##[debug]Arguments:
 ##[debug]Arguments:
 ##[debug] 65001
 ##[debug] 65001
 [command]C:\Windows\system32\chcp.com 65001
 Active code page: 65001
 ##[debug]solution=d:\a\1\s\Contracts\SNR3\SNR3.sln
 ##[debug]System.DefaultWorkingDirectory=d:\a\1\s
 ##[debug]pattern: d:\a\1\s\Contracts\SNR3\SNR3.sln, isNegative: false
 ##[debug]check path : d:\a\1\s\Contracts\SNR3\SNR3.sln
 ##[error]Error: Not found files: d:\a\1\s\Contracts\SNR3\SNR3.sln
 ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.issue type=error;]Error: Not found files: d:\a\1\s\Contracts\SNR3\SNR3.sln
 ##[debug]task result: Failed
 ##[error]Packages failed to install
 ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.issue type=error;]Packages failed to install
 ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.complete result=Failed;]Packages failed to install
 ##[section]Finishing: NuGet install $/Contracts/SNR3/SNR3.sln
 ##[debug]Evaluating condition for step: 'Build solution $/Contracts/SNR3/SNR3.sln'
 ##[debug]Evaluating: succeeded()
 ##[debug]Evaluating succeeded:
 ##[debug]=> (Boolean) False
 ##[debug]Expanded: False
 ##[debug]Result: False
 ##[debug]Evaluating condition for step: 'Publish Artifact: drop'
 ##[debug]Evaluating: succeededOrFailed()
 ##[debug]Evaluating succeededOrFailed:
 ##[debug]=> (Boolean) True
 ##[debug]Expanded: True
 ##[debug]Result: True
 ##[section]Starting: Publish Artifact: drop
 ==============================================================================
 Task : Publish Build Artifacts
 Description : Publish Build artifacts to the server or a file share
 Version : 1.0.41
 Author : Microsoft Corporation
 Help : [More Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=708390)
 ==============================================================================
 ##[debug]agent.workFolder=d:\a
 ##[debug]loading inputs and endpoints
 ##[debug]loading ENDPOINT_AUTH_$/
 ##[debug]loading ENDPOINT_AUTH_PARAMETER_$/_ACCESSTOKEN
 ##[debug]loading ENDPOINT_AUTH_PARAMETER_SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION_ACCESSTOKEN
 ##[debug]loading ENDPOINT_AUTH_SCHEME_$/
 ##[debug]loading ENDPOINT_AUTH_SCHEME_SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION
 ##[debug]loading ENDPOINT_AUTH_SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION
 ##[debug]loading INPUT_ARTIFACTNAME
 ##[debug]loading INPUT_ARTIFACTTYPE
 ##[debug]loading INPUT_PATHTOPUBLISH
 ##[debug]loading INPUT_TARGETPATH
 ##[debug]loaded 10
 ##[debug]check path : d:\a\_tasks\PublishBuildArtifacts_2ff763a7-ce83-4e1f-bc89-0ae63477cebe\1.0.41\task.json
 ##[debug]set resource file to: d:\a\_tasks\PublishBuildArtifacts_2ff763a7-ce83-4e1f-bc89-0ae63477cebe\1.0.41\task.json
 ##[debug]system.culture=en-US
 ##[debug]system.hostType=build
 ##[debug]PathtoPublish=d:\a\1\a\AppxPackages
 ##[debug]check path : d:\a\1\a\AppxPackages
 ##[debug]task result: Failed
 ##[error]Publish build artifacts failed with error: Not found PathtoPublish: d:\a\1\a\AppxPackages
 ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.issue type=error;]Publish build artifacts failed with error: Not found PathtoPublish: d:\a\1\a\AppxPackages
 ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.complete result=Failed;]Publish build artifacts failed with error: Not found PathtoPublish: d:\a\1\a\AppxPackages
 ##[section]Finishing: Publish Artifact: drop
 ##[debug]Evaluating condition for step: 'Post Job Cleanup'
 ##[debug]Always run post-job step: 'Post Job Cleanup'
 ##[section]Starting: Post Job Cleanup
 ##[section]Finishing: Post Job Cleanup
 ##[debug]Cleaning agent temp folder: d:\a\_temp
 ##[section]Finishing: Build
```

Feed URL:
http://nuget.syncfusion.com/nuget_universalwindows/nuget/getsyncfusionpackages/universalwindows

Things that make my situation a little unique, I am using a custom NuGet feed for Syncfusion controls. I did read of it being absolutely necessary to have a NuGet.config (one is not generated in VS2017 and UWP Creator's Update builds apparently) with custom feeds so I did that, added it to my source control, and checked it in.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <clear />
    <add key="Syncfusion UWP" value="http://nuget.syncfusion.com/nuget_universalwindows/nuget/getsyncfusionpackages/universalwindows" />
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" />
  </packageSources>
  <activePackageSource>
    <add key="All" value="(Aggregate source)" />
  </activePackageSource>
</configuration>
```

Things I have tried:

- NuGet Task v 0.* instead of 1.*
- NuGet Install vs. Restore
- NuGet version 3.3.0, 3.5.0, 4.0.0
- Starting from scratch with UWP template.
- Starting from scratch with Generics Visual Studio template.
- Build agent, Default (doesn't work), Hosted, and Hosted 2017.

Below are the screenshots for the latest UI / config options.  Perhaps someone can see my mistake?

[image: Source Control / Workspace Map]

[image: Tasks - Processes]

[image: Get Sources]

[image: NuGet Install]

[image: Build]

[image: Copy Files]

[image: Publish]

Comment: Did you receive any warning when you installed VS2017? I had an issue with Xamarin because the installation wasn't "clear".

Comment: Based on the log, it says All files are up to date and the Workingfolder is d:\a\1\s\Contracts with $/Contracts (different with Workspace mappings you configured), it seems files are not downloaded, try to create a new build definition, queue build and check the result.

Comment: They were just logs from different runs I apologize. I have tried re-working all of this several times.  D:\a\1\s\  just happened to be the local directory in that run mapped to $Contracts\SNR3. I have tried every combination known to man. If I had to guess, it's not copying the source code to the source folder. When I do the recommended settings all it does is scan the $tf folder, which is in a directory above Contracts... so it isn't even in the scope of the repository! @shinjidev I did not and this is not a Xamarin solution.

Comment: Can you provide the latest build log? What's the result if you try it with a new build definition?

Comment: I have done so. Updated original post.

Comment: @starain-MSFT I have rectified my issue by deleting my entire Visual Studio TS account. Started from scratch re-importing my solution. A pain but it works now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have rectified my issue by deleting my entire Visual Studio Team Services (VSTS Online) account.

- Created a new VSTS Online Account.
- Created a new Project.
- Created the local mappings (my dev box).
- Opened my solution, added to source control, and checked in changes.

Hopefully, this helps anyone else who gets stuck on this.

I successfully used VSTS to CI Build a UWP (Creator's Update 2017) application with these settings:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You can go to version control admin page (https://[account].visualstudio.com/[project]/_admin/_versioncontrol) and select a item, then check Project Collection Build Service and Project Collection Build Service Accounts permission (Read). On the other hand, you can accept it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

According to the logs, you are using Hosted Build Agent which means that the source code should not exist on the build agent before. But the build logs indicates that there is no file been downloaded in the first "Get Sources" step since "All files are up to date".

```
 ##[command]tf vc workspace /new /location:local /permission:Public ws_1_1 /collection:https://houseofcat.visualstudio.com/ /loginType:OAuth /login:.,******** /noprompt
 ##[command]tf vc workfold /unmap /workspace:ws_1_1 $/ /collection:https://houseofcat.visualstudio.com/ /loginType:OAuth /login:.,******** /noprompt
 ##[command]tf vc workfold /map /workspace:ws_1_1 $/Contracts d:\a\1\s\Contracts /collection:https://houseofcat.visualstudio.com/ /loginType:OAuth /login:.,******** /noprompt
 ##[command]tf vc workfold /cloak /workspace:ws_1_1 $/Contracts/Drops /collection:https://houseofcat.visualstudio.com/ /loginType:OAuth /login:.,******** /noprompt
 ##[command]tf vc get /version:494 /recursive /overwrite d:\a\1\s /loginType:OAuth /login:.,******** /noprompt
 All files are up to date.
```

This could be caused by:

1. Your source code isn't checked into VSTS successfully. Open VSTS Web Portal and then go to "Code" hub to check if you can see your source code.
2. The "Workspace mappings" in incorrect in "Get Sources" step. Click "..." button to select the correct folder you'd like to map and then try the build again.
   [image]

Comment: Both are checked in, and I navigated directly to the SLN in the screenshots if you noticed. Meaning TFS repository was available when FolderPicker opened. Meaning it was able to read the files there.

Comment: I have quite literally tried every folder in the repository, for workspace mapping, after I tried the obvious ones. I mean I absolutely believe you, but I can't force VSTS / TFS to see the files, you know what I mean?